# Calling a function template in a pack expansion pattern

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Let's keep it short. Why does the following code compile successfully...

```
#define RUN_FORALL(pattern) (int[]){0, ((pattern), void(), 0)...}
template <typename ...Attributes>
class Foo : public Attributes... {
  template <typename T>
  void bar(T o) { RUN_FORALL(Attributes::value = o.getValue()); }
};
int main() {}
```

... and the following code does not?

```
#define RUN_FORALL(pattern) (int[]){0, ((pattern), void(), 0)...}
template <typename ...Attributes>
class Foo : public Attributes... {
  template <typename T>
  void bar(T o) { RUN_FORALL(Attributes::value = o.getValue<Attributes>()); }
};
int main() {}
```

Error:

```
1:30: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
5:19: note: in expansion of macro 'RUN_FORALL'
```

How can I call a function template in a pack expansion pattern?

Comment: Do you think you could provide a [mcve]? I'd like to compile the top snippet myself.

Comment: Missing `template` disambiguation, my friend. Also `(int[]) { .. }` is non-standard syntax borrowed from C.

Comment: @AndyG I am not sure what you are missing. You can take both snippets, copy them as they are to e.g. `www.cpp.sh` and observe that the above compiles successfully and the below does not.

Comment: `o.template getValue<Attributes>()`. This has nothing to do with pack expansions.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Are you sure that this is non-standard syntax? Have a look at [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization): `T { arg1, arg2, ... };` initializes an unnamed temporary with a braced-init-list.

Comment: @user1494080 yes.. you can ask a new question if you are unsure about it. it is nonstandard and not shown on the site you link

Comment: `(int []) { stuff }` is a C99 compound literal. The `T` in C++ has to be a *simple-type-specifier* or a *typename-specifier*; `(int [])` is neither.